# why are all my new netbeans projects managed by subversion by default?

Tags: svn, netbeans

when i create a new netbeans project netbeans tend to manage it with subversion by default.

i dont want that.

is it a way to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is not being monitored by svn if you create it in a directory that is not monitored by svn.

Let's take a quick 'example'...

Say you have checked out some code from an SVN repository, into the folder /home/mine/foo.  foo becomes your SVN_ROOT.... All the code in any sub directory of foo came from your svn directory.  If you create a project in /home/mine/foo/NewNBProject, NetBeans (and the svn command line program) will assume that you want this new project to be checked into the svn repo, eventually.

If you create your project in /home/mine/bar/NewNBProject, NetBeans will not associate the project's files with a repository [assuming you did not use svn to get bar from an svn repository].

Answer (score 0):

What kind of projects are you creating in Netbeans? I have used Netbeans to create new Java and new Ruby projects without this issue. Could it be that you are creating a new SVN project by mistake?

Comment: i click: file -> php -> php application. its a new php 5 application that will be created from scratch. but it will be svn monitored once created. and i have no idea why.